# OpenGL ES performance: updating transforms in a large VBO at minimum cost?

Tags: ios, opengl-es

I'm writing an app for my creaky old iPad 3 that uses hardware-accelerated vector graphics, and I'd like to maximize my performance. As a representative test case, let's say I have a grid (think graph paper) comprised of 100 rows and 240 columns, for a total of `(100 + 240) * 2 = 640` triangles (since each line is a polygon). If I go past this limit, or if I do anything more than just drawing the grid, my framerate slips from my target of 60 to 20-30 and everything gets jittery. I feel I should get better results than that.

Some details. My triangles are stored in a VBO. I am presently using Cocos2D's batched CCSprite implementation, which uses `glMapBufferRangeEXT` and `glFlushMappedBufferRangeEXT` to update and flush the buffer ever single frame. It's very important to me that each grid line be independently movable and scalable; I want to be able to change the grid properties (e.g. distance between rows or columns) and immediately see the change be animated. I also wish to dynamically change the thickness of my lines as I zoom in and out. For this reason, I can't just leave my VBO alone (treating it as a static mesh) and simply apply transforms to it; I need to be able to dynamically adjust my lines in every frame.

It seems to me that the blocking issue here is the fact that I'm pumping so much data between the CPU and GPU in every frame, so presumably I need to find ways of minimizing this flow. Getting rid of the VBO and simply drawing each line individually does not work; I get far too many draw calls and my framerate drops substantially. So what I essentially need to do is to find a way to apply transforms to specific triangles in my VBO in each frame at a minimum cost. In my particular use case, there are far less unique transforms than there are vertices; when I zoom my grid out, for example, I scale the width and adjust the position of each line identically. In another part of my program, I found a way to quickly adjust the color of my VBO triangles by mapping each vert to individual pixels of a long, 1x4096 texture on creation. All I have to do to change the colors of my lines is to update the corresponding pixels in my texture, which modifies the properties of dozens or even hundreds of triangles at once with just a single `glTexSubImage2D` call. It seems like this principle should apply to things like transforms as well, but doing it through a texture seems hacky (if not impossible, since I'm not sure you can bind more than one texture to a vert).

Is there a "best practices" way to do this sort of thing without having to update the entire VBO? Some shader magic? Mapping something-or-other to a texture? Partial updates of the VBO? Or a completely standard method that I have yet to discover?

Or perhaps I'm approaching the problem the completely wrong way?

Comment: 640 triangles isn't a lot of data at all.  Can you use an Instruments Time Profile to examine where the time is being spent?  If you're seeing performance issues with that amount of data, then it is possible the driver is falling back to software vertex submission (memcopying all the data).

Comment: Yeah, that's another problem with my novice-ness. I have little idea of the performance characteristics of OpenGL. 640 triangles doesn't sound like a lot, but at the same time, it's a 20000-40000 element array that's getting completely updated and uploaded to the GPU in every frame. (640 * 3 * 12, because CC2D has a bunch of extra data for each vert in addition to the positions). And the iPad 3 has notoriously poor graphics performance given its resolution, though I'm not sure if it matters for what I'm doing.

Comment: Or am I mistaken that the data gets re-uploaded? I just remembered that iOS devices use shared memory with the GPU. Do the buffer mapping calls mean that the data is simply shared instead of being copied? (Thinking about it now, it seems rather obvious. As I said, novice...)

Comment: *I'm pumping so much data between the CPU and GPU in every frame, so presumably I need to find ways of minimizing this flow.* I just ran into exact the same issue. Have you found a solution to this? @Archagon

Comment: @zwcloud Yes — I dropped VBOs entirely once I discovered geometry streaming, which is what Cocos2d does in version 3 and onwards. Basically, you bind (map) a section of local RAM to GPU memory and then copy (stream) your geometry data to it anew in every frame. This works surprisingly fast and eliminates most of the horrifying VBO state management. It's advised that you either double-buffer this memory or increase the size of your buffer to accommodate some number of extra frames to avoid frequent realloc. More here: http://archagon.net/blog/2016/02/27/path-rendering-in-composers-sketchpad/

Comment: @zwcloud I think I also had a solution for the VBO approach, but it involved some gnarly batching and custom shaders. I was very happy to scrap it once I got streaming working!

Comment: @Archagon Thank you very much! I will try your approach.